# Centering "limes" , i.e., "\lim_{...}" term, before long fraction

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to write the eqaution

```
\[ 
\lim_{x \to \Delta x}\dfrac {\dfrac {f(x + \Delta x) - f(x-\Delta)} {2\Delta x} + 
\dfrac {f(y + \Delta y) - f(y-\Delta)} {2\Delta y}} {2}
\]
```

However I want limes centered vertically. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to center the term `\lim_{...}` vertically relative to the compound-fraction expression. (Note that the limes expression is centered relative to the main fraction bar.)

I can think of two alternative solutions; both work by not using compound `\frac` statements:

- Extract the common term `\frac{1}{2}`, and use round parentheses and curly braces as needed to indicate grouping.
- Use inline-fraction notation for the terms in the numerator of the "outer" `\frac`.

Speaking for myself, I'd prefer the first solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\dfrac' macro
\begin{document}

Original form
\[
\lim_{x \to \Delta x}\dfrac {\dfrac {f(x + \Delta x) - f(x-\Delta)} {2\Delta x} +
\dfrac {f(y + \Delta y) - f(y-\Delta)} {2\Delta y}} {2}
\]

\bigskip
Solution 1: extract the multiplicative \verb+\frac{1}{2}+ factor
\[
\lim_{x \to \Delta x} \biggl\{ \frac{1}{2} 
\biggl(
   \frac {f(x + \Delta x) - f(x-\Delta)} {2\Delta x} +
   \frac {f(y + \Delta y) - f(y-\Delta)} {2\Delta y}
\biggl) \biggr\}
\]

\bigskip
Solution 2: use inline fraction notation for terms in numerator
\[
\lim_{x \to \Delta x}
\frac {[f(x + \Delta x) - f(x-\Delta)]/(2\Delta x)
      +[f(y + \Delta y) - f(y-\Delta)]/(2\Delta y)} {2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the fact that the formula is meaningless, you *may* center “lim” with respect to the big fraction, but at the reader’s expense, who will have a hard time in understanding what the thing is meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Ugly}

\[
\lim_{x \to \Delta x}
\begin{gathered}
\dfrac {\dfrac {f(x + \Delta x) - f(x-\Delta)} {2\Delta x} +
\dfrac {f(y + \Delta y) - f(y-\Delta)} {2\Delta y}} {2}
\end{gathered}
\]

\section{Bad}

\[
\lim_{x \to \Delta x}\dfrac {\dfrac {f(x + \Delta x) - f(x-\Delta)} {2\Delta x} +
\dfrac {f(y + \Delta y) - f(y-\Delta)} {2\Delta y}} {2}
\]

\section{Good}

\[
\lim_{x \to \Delta x}\frac{1}{2}\left(
  \dfrac {f(x + \Delta x) - f(x-\Delta)} {2\Delta x} +
  \dfrac {f(y + \Delta y) - f(y-\Delta)} {2\Delta y} \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]